# triangle circle inside it, heights prove exercise

Tags: circles, triangles

Point $O$ lie inside $ABC$ triangle. Points $A1,B1,C1$ are projections of $O$ on heights led  from $A,B,C$ Prove that if $AA1=BB1=CC1$ then $AA1=2r$, where $r$ is radius of circle inscribed in $ABC$ triangle.
I 'd be happy with a hint that will lead me to answer

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- there can be only one point $O$ such that $AA_1=BB_1=CC_1$
- show that [Nagel point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NagelPoint.html) has the desired property - it is quite easy if you know [van Aubel's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanAubelsTheorem.html) (the second one)